# SQL Server 2019 AG Sync Slow After Failover - Stuck In Reverting State

Tags: sql-server

I have a database in an AWS AG that is very busy and can produce up to 40 GB of logs every 30 minutes. When I manually fail over the AG, the new secondary database is stuck in the reverting state and eventually the log drive on the primary fills as it can't flush its logs to the database on the secondary until it becomes synced.

I've read this can be a very slow process (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/troubleshoot-availability-group-database-reverting-state) - are there any ways to speed this up in any way as the app then eventually becomes unavailable because of the full log drive.

We are running a x2iedn.8xlarge with 1TB of memory and very fast drives: gp3 16000 IOPS for DATA, io2 16000 IOPS for LOG. The AG is synchronous with automatic fail over.

We also have log backups running every 10 mins - strangely the size of these files grow massively until the log drive fills, then they drop to near zero, despite the database log file still being full?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you checked How many VLF you have?

Comment: Yes I set growth to 1gb and initially created a 300gb file. I think it's the fact there are long running large queries at the time of fail over that need to be rolled back/synced. It just seems so slow to finish.

Comment: Then you need to take a look at storage performance. do you face high PAGELATCH_IO or disk latency and high redo log size?

Comment: Did you recently migrate to aws and into a 1 TB server?  If so this could be something to consider.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/performance/buffer-pool-scan-runs-slowly-large-memory-machines

Comment: We have the same issue and we have also raised case with MS which has been open for 7 months and no root cause.  They initially said it was this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/performance/buffer-pool-scan-runs-slowly-large-memory-machines
We also had issue where new primary was taking 5 mins to come online which was sped up by dropcleanbuffer on the secondary before failover.
they dont have a clue about why it is stuck in reverting state, but apparanly for we have large number of db files, so for every file it does some sort of buffer pool scan which

Comment: takes 10 sec for each file, so for us 80 files so it takes total of 13 mins.  Now as to why it is doing it, they have no idea.  Even weirder the issue randomly pops up in the pre prod environment and goes away, so I know it has some trigger.  Extremely frustrating MS is taking this long to figure out what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

> When I manually fail over the AG, the new secondary database is stuck in the reverting state and eventually the log drive on the primary fills as it can't flush its logs to the database on the secondary until it becomes synced.

I would choose a better time to failover. Reverting is common and happens all the time, however it generally lasts for such a short amount of time that people don't realize it's happening. After reverting, it'll also need to go through initializing, and then it'll become syncrhoniz(ed/ing).

> [...] are there any ways to speed this up in any way as the app then eventually becomes unavailable because of the full log drive.

There are no knobs to turn in SQL Server for [fast failovers](https://www.seangallardy.com/availability-group-long-failover-times/) per se. If you'd like to understand how it works and monitoring [then this will help](https://www.seangallardy.com/undo-of-redo-reverting-and-initializing/).

There are some indirect things you can do:

1. Choose an opportune time to fail over. Stay away from large imports or batches, choose times of lower change rates. This will result in a lower amount of data to undo.
2. If you have a large number of database files and max server memory is set high, setting max server memory very low can help to reduce the hardware cost of memory scanning per file.
3. Choose to reseed the database rather than wait for reverting and initializing.

Comment: Unfortunately the DB is 24x7 busy. I'm also wanting it to naturally sync again if say it fails over through the night, and not fill the log drive.

Comment: @SteveHindle If you have a recent enough version, you can try enabling ADR, but the main problem is that there was a lot of items that needed to be rolled back, a lot. It can be busy and have such a short reverting phase that you don't even know, it's really about open transactions, especially large ones.

Comment: I was reading about ADR yesterday so it's an option we are looking at. Thanks for you responses.

Comment: Thanks for the responses - great site by the way: https://www.seangallardy.com/